# Change css value depending on the database value asp.net

Tags: css, sql, asp.net

Im using sql server and aspx. I want the value in the table to change color depending on the value in sql in the code behind file. So, if the value in one of the table == "yes" change the color #ff0000. If the value in the table is == "no" change it to #00ff00; Table is called: submitTable and the column is status. I'm using Gridview.

```
<asp:GridView ID="gridlistUsers" runat="server" HorizontalAlign="left" AutoGenerateColumns="false" CssClass="table table-bordered " GridLines="None">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" HeaderText="TicketNumber" HeaderStyle-CssClass="Color" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" HeaderText="TicketNumber" HeaderStyle-CssClass="Color" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Status" HeaderText="Opened/Closed" HeaderStyle-CssClass="Color" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: Where is your code and a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? What kind of `Table` are you talking about for example.

Comment: I've added some code @VDWWD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've gotten it to work! This helped me too http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Change-Background-color-of-GridView-Row-using-RowDataBound-event-in-ASPNet-using-C-and-VBNet.aspx

```
 <asp:GridView ID="gridlistUsers" runat="server" HorizontalAlign="left" AutoGenerateColumns="false" CssClass="table table-bordered " OnRowDataBound = "OnRowDataBound">
```

//code behind

```
 protected void OnRowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                TableCell cell = e.Row.Cells[0];  //the 0 changes depending on the column number in sql
                string status = (cell.Text);
                string yes = "yes";
                string no = "no";

                if (status.Equals(no))
                {
                    cell.BackColor = Color.Red;
                }
                if (status.Equals(yes))
                {
                    cell.BackColor = Color.Green;
                }


            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

You should do the job in asp to create an REST API for this sql table.
Then with Ajax & JS you could GET this values for each html table and save to variables.

And then with simple:

```
if (your_sql_value === "yes") {
    document.querySelector('.css-class').style.backgroundColor = "#ff0000"
} else if (your_sql_value === "no") {
    document.querySelector('.css-class').style.backgroundColor = "#00ff00"
}
```

Comment: I actually need it for a grideview not table

Answer (score 1):

From your answer, i'm assuming you're using an asp:Table.

So basically there are two ways this could go:

**1. Your table is already filled and rendered**

If this is the case, check this table example:

**Image:**

[image]

**.ASPX Table Code:**

```
<asp:Table ID="submitTable" runat="server" GridLines="Both">
    <asp:TableRow runat="server" HorizontalAlign="Center" TableSection="TableHeader" VerticalAlign="Middle">
        <asp:TableCell runat="server" Width="128px">ID</asp:TableCell>
        <asp:TableCell runat="server" Width="128px">Status</asp:TableCell>
    </asp:TableRow>
</asp:Table>
```

It is a table filled with random values of either "yes" or "no". In this situation, you could iterate through each row and simply apply the color attribute like this:

```
int statusColumnIndex = 1; // Because it is the second column

int k = 0;
foreach (TableRow row in submitTable.Rows)
{
    if(k != 0) // Do this so it won't color the header row
    {
        if( row.Cells[statusColumnIndex].Text.Equals("yes") )
        {
            row.Cells[statusColumnIndex].BackColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 0, 0); // 255, 0, 0 is #ff0000 in RGB
        }

        else
        {
            row.Cells[statusColumnIndex].BackColor = Color.FromArgb(0, 255, 0); // 0, 255, 0 is ##00ff00 in RGB
        }
    }
    k++;
}
```

**Result (different random values):**

[image]

or

**2. If you want to color the table as you fill the table**

In this case, you could apply a color to it when you instantiate the TableCell objects to fill the TableRow:

```
string statusValueFromSql = valueFromSqlQuery;
Color color;

if( statusValueFromSql.Equals("yes") )
{
    color = Color.FromArgb(255, 0, 0); // 255, 0, 0 is #ff0000 in RGB
}
else
{
    color = Color.FromArgb(0, 255, 0); // 0, 255, 0 is ##00ff00 in RGB
}

var cellStatus = new TableCell { BackColor = color };
```

The end result is exactly the same as situation 1.

I hope my answer helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `OnRowDataBound` event for that.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound">
```

Code behind

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    //check if the row is a datarow
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        //cast the current row as a datarowview
        DataRowView row = e.Row.DataItem as DataRowView;

        //check the correct column value 
        if (Convert.ToBoolean(row["Status"]) == false)
        {
            //set the color of the row directly
            e.Row.BackColor = Color.Red;

            //or change it's class
            e.Row.CssClass = "Red";

            //or change a property per cell
            e.Row.Cells[0].CssClass = "Blue";
            e.Row.Cells[1].BackColor = Color.Purple;
        }
    }
}
```